# cl_demo_output=>display data type not yet supported

Tags: abap

In ABAP 7.4 OR above, We can use ASTERISK as much the same way as we use in SELECT *.

Following inner join is an example of new syntax which we can use.

```
 SELECT scarr~carrname, spfli~*, scarr~url
        FROM scarr INNER JOIN spfli ON scarr~carrid = spfli~carrid
        INTO TABLE @DATA(t_result).
```

I am facing error when trying to display output by using below statement.

```
 cl_demo_output=>display( t_result ).
```

The error message is "data type not yet supported"

Can anyone explain the reason ?

what could be the better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In release 7.40, or even in ABAP 7.52, `cl_demo_output=>display` can only display an internal table with a list of [**elementary**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenbuilt_in_types_complete.htm) components (`string`, `i`, `c`, etc.)

In your case, the internal table `t_result` is automatically declared with three components, the second one being a [**structure**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abendata_objects_structure.htm), which is not an elementary type.

It's a structure because you used `~*`. Instead, declare each column explicitly (`spfli~carrid, spfli~connid, ...`)

NB: the class `cl_demo_output` should not be used productively. If you need a generic tool, create your own tool, for instance based on the class `cl_salv_table`.

Answer (score 0):

From ABAP release 7.56, SP01 on, CL_DEMO_OUTPUT supports any type.

https://blogs.sap.com/2021/12/08/cl_demo_output-invigorated/